# NGINX Proxy pass to external site that has internal redirect

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

i'm trying to configure an nginx proxy that hide an internal site via the proxy pass but without success.
the config i used is

```
location /internal1/ {
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   proxy_connect_timeout 15;
   proxy_read_timeout 180;
   proxy_pass http://internal1/;
}

upstream internal1 {
   server a.b.c.d:80;
}
```

the problem is that when i try to reach the a.b.c.d site it redirect to a login page that sould be http://a.b.c.d/login and after i login it redirect at another page http://a.b.c.d/device/config . with the proxy it redirect to http://mysite/login and http://mysite/device/config

that make the proxy do not work and show me resource not found and i couldn not see any of the pages.

If i change the proxy_pass value to http://a.b.c.d/login/ it show the login page at http://mysite/internal1 and after i login it show no resource found because it try to reach http://mysite/device/config.

someone have some suggestion on how to configure it in the proper way?

thanks for all the answer

EDIT:
sorry for the late answer but i got very busy in the meanwhile, anyway that solution work for 1 device but now all my device connected go only that device "internal" page and i cannot differentiate between more cause nginx do not support the same location in multiple config ( all device have ip/page1 )

```
location /page1/
{ 
 proxy_pass mysite/internal1/page1;
 proxy_redirect off;
 proxy_set_header Host $host;
}
```

EDIT2:
unlucky it's not possible to expose all device to internet directly. the solution i found is:

create a custom DNS subdomain and then create a different nginx server block for every device with his own location and future redirect/proxy ecc...

Comment: You should present your main website as `/main` and the hidden website as `/internal` - using 2 `location` blocks. Then you will have a catch-all location of `/` - which will proxy_pass just like `/internal`. In this way you will be able to distinguish between the main site and the hidden site - so that when the internal site redirects to something that is not `/main` you will be able to catch it.

Comment: I try to use your solution and qith some more config work only for the login page but not the next page. basically when it go to http://site/internal it show the http://a.b.c.d./login page correctly but then it show no resource again.

Comment: Perhaps the internal site uses its IP address in the redirects instead of its domain name? You may need to change its code to use the `Host` HTTP header.

Comment: Unluckily the internal site is a device that show a webpage and i cannot change how this work

Comment: Then you will have to rewrite the `Location` header that is returned from the device before sending it back to the browser.

Comment: i edit my question with a little more datail, sorry again for late response

Comment: You can try to use port forwarding on your router instead of proxying with nginX - and simply unhide all devices to Internet.

Comment: can you pls post an answer with your first 2 comment so i can mark as correct answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to expose the web UI of all your devices that live in the internal network to be accessible through Internet - then you will have to create a subdomain (and a corresponding virtual host config) for each device.

Suppose that the domain that points to your nginX is `mydevices.net` and that you have 2 devices - on 192.168.2.10 and 192.168.2.20

Then your nginX config will look like this:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name dev1.mydevices.net;

  location / {
    proxy_pass internal1;
    proxy_redirect default;
  }
}

upstream internal1 {
   server 192.168.2.10;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name dev2.mydevices.net;

  location / {
    proxy_pass internal2;
    proxy_redirect default;
  }
}

upstream internal2 {
   server 192.168.2.20;
}
```